# Change Linux boot partition

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning

I want to install a newer Ubuntu distro beside my existing one. At later time I want to delete my old distro and move my new Ubuntu to the partition where the old one was. By doing so, boot configuration of my new Ubuntu would be incorrect. How do I fix this?

Comment: If you can, try installing the new one in a partition beside the old one. This way, instead of moving the new one, you can remove the old partition and extend the new one. Extending the partition is much easier than moving the OS to another partition. After that you just need to `update-grub`

Comment: May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info Depends if UEFI or BIOS. Usually most recent install takes over ESP(UEFI) or MBR (BIOS). May just need to boot into new install and re-install grub from there. `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` and then `sudo update-grub`